# Will the Apache License or the GPL License protect my trademarks?

Tags: open-source, gpl, apache-license, trademark

I'm trying to see if these two open source licenses give protection of trademarks to the originator. I have read both licenses but they only seem to talk about their own trademark i.e. 'Apache'.

Answer (score 4):

In general, trademark protection is a separate issue from software distribution.  Your trademarks are supposed to be already protected under a wide range of circumstances, regardless of any licenses you might use to distribute software or otherwise sell product.

That said, trademark and copyright protection are often re-affirmed in software licenses.  Section 6 in the Apache license does this; it states:

> This License does not grant permission to use the trade names,
>   trademarks, service marks, or product names of the Licensor, except as
>   required for reasonable and customary use in describing the origin of
>   the Work and reproducing the content of the NOTICE file.